# TargetFrameworkVersion in Assembly-CSCharp.csproj not saving changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, csproj

I'm using VS Code as code editor, with c# and unity extensions (to auto-complete functions and variables). When i created unity project, i opened folder of project in vs code - where compiler were throw error (When i cant use fast-fill commands)

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: w:\projects\2D game\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

I am tried to change file directly, but unity automaticly changing version to 4.7.1, in Unity editor and in project settings i dont found current setting.

In google writes to change TargetFrameworkVerison in csproj file - but i cant to do that. After saving, and opening C# project in unity - changes dont applied, unity automaticly changes version to 4.7.1 (current version .NET Framework is 4.8.1)

[image]

Comment: well the Unity version you are using (`2021.3.16f1`) uses `4.7.1` ... there is no use in modifying auto-generated things like the `Assembly-CSCharp.csproj` as Unity will re-generate them anyway

Comment: Well. Where i can check targeting .NET versions of other versions of Unity?